# Improving the feel and clarity in the message

Tags: usability, user-expectation

I am developing a carpool app. After launch, I encourage the user of my app to hit the "carpool button". So I do a search closeby to see if there are any users. If I find people closeby, I check the device contact list if this person is a known contact, I want to show a wonderful message that encourages the user to carpool with a known person.

If you notice, a dropdown appears indicating that some `are your contacts`. I think the message is not clear enough. Also not encouraging enough.

[image: carEgiri carpool india]

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how this interface works.  The 'RIDES AROUND YOU' panel looks like some kind of overlay. Why does it hide the top of the form?

Comment: It only shows up for 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Don't understand interaction between checkbox "I'll drive today" and "now" and "today" button. Same problem with "I'm now at" and "Current Location"

Comment: When you hit the checkbox, the text on the button changes from NEED A RIDE to OFFER A RIDE. I hear you about I'm now at and Current Location. Can we a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be in a small overlay panel. There is no reason to not indicate how many of them you know.

"There are X rides close by"

"And you know Y of them"